# android sharedPreferences's clear function not working

Tags: android, singleton, sharedpreferences

My Pref's clear is not working.

This is my PreferencManager.java

```
public class PreferenceManager {
  private static final String PREF_NAME = "my_prefs.xml";

  private static PreferenceManager instance;
  private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
  private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

  public static PreferenceManager getInstance(Context context) {
      if (instance == null) {
          instance = new PreferenceManager(context);
      }
      return instance;
  }


  private PreferenceManager(Context context) {
      mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
  }

  private static final String UUID = "UUID";
  private String uuid = "";

  public void setUuid(String key) {
      this.uuid = key;
      clear(UUID);
      mEditor.putString(UUID, key);
      mEditor.commit();
  }

  public String getUuid() {
      if (uuid.equals("")) {
          uuid = mPrefs.getString(UUID, "");
      }
      return uuid;
  }
  //clear
  public void clear(String key) {
      mEditor.remove(key);
      mEditor.commit();
  }
  public void allClear(){
      mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
      mEditor.clear();
      mEditor.commit();
  }
}
```

When I use it in my Activity like this

```
PreferenceMangaer.getInstance(getApplicationContext).setUUID("ok");
```

or

```
String result= PreferenceMangaer.getInstance(getApplicationContext).getUUID;
```

When I debugging, clear(UUID) is not working and allClear as well.
Why it dose not work?

i try both commit() and apply().

I'm waiting for your help
Thank you

Comment: You saving values with "UUID" key but trying to removing with the different key.

Comment: I don't even see the `setPushKey` and `getPushKey` methods on your `PreferenceManager`.

Comment: @gokhan
Sorry This is my mistake, i edit my question. please check it up again. Thanks to your reply

Comment: @dr3k Sorry This is my mistake, i edit my question. please check it up again. Thanks to your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also did not clear your global `uuid`.

```
  public void allClear(){
      this.uuid = ""; // Clears the global uuid.
      mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
      mEditor.clear();
      mEditor.commit();
  }
```

So that's why your `getUuid` gets the same result as before.

You don't have to store a local reference of `uuid`.

```
  private static final String UUID = "UUID";

  public void setUuid(String key) {
      mEditor.putString(UUID, key);
      mEditor.apply(); // better use apply() instead commit()
  }

  public String getUuid() {
      return mPrefs.getString(UUID, "");
  }

  //clear
  public void clear(String key) {
      mEditor.remove(key);
      mEditor.apply();
  }
  public void allClear(){
      mEditor.clear();
      mEditor.apply(); 
  }
```

Comment: Exactly correct!! Thank you so much. I understand what i was doing wrong:)

Answer (score 0):

use a key and editor function.

```
    SharedPreferences Prefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Prefs.edit();
    editor.remove(String key);
    editor.apply()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.